# Node - Express page redirection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Page redirect not working `return res.redirect('/logout');`

Current url http://localhost:3000/abc/cccccc -
Re-direction to http://localhost:3000/logout

```
exports.tokenVeryAndNext = async (req, res, next) => {
    let token =   req.cookies.token;
    if(token == null || token == "undefined") { 
        return res.redirect('/logout'); 
    }
    try{
        let decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_KEY_2);
        let userDoc = await User.findById(decoded.id);
        console.log(userDoc)
        req.user = userDoc;
        next();
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.name, "jwt error");
        return res.redirect('/logout');  
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, you don't "return" res.redirect!

Comment: If I remove return , getting error //(node:12213) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
// @PraveenKumarPurushothaman

Comment: Ah, that's bad.